# Identical PCI SSDs on the computer, is there a tool I can run from a live Linux USB and physically mirror bit by bit one SSD into the other one?

Tags: ssd

They are Samsung SSD and I can use the Data Migration tool in Windows, but would prefer an option in Linux

Comment: Are you asking for a one-time copy of the data from one SSD to another, or are you asking to create an on-going duplication of data written to the two SSDs?

Answer (score 1):

`cat` will do the job.  as would `dd`.  and many other tools.

e.g. assuming the source drive is nvme0n1 and the target drive is nvme1n1:

```
cat /dev/nvme0n1 > /dev/nvme1n1
```

```
dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/nvme1n1
```

---

If instead of just a once-off copy, you wanted an on-going mirror for the two drives, you could use `mdadm` or LVM and set up a RAID-1 array, or use `btrfs` as the filesystem or, better yet, ZFS.

Comment: If using `dd` - I highly recommend setting a larger block size - ad why not add some progress report?
`dd if=/dev/nvme0n1  of=/dev/nvme1n1 bs=16M status=progress`